# Adding description to RestEasy's web service parameters?

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs, documentation-generation, resteasy

Is there some way/annotation by which I can add the description to the parameters of a RestEasy web service? I went through the [api-doc](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/package-tree.html) of the annotations, but found nothing there.

This is in order to add the descriptions so that they are reflected in the REST API documentation which I'll be auto-generating using some tool.

An example web service interface:

```
@Path("list-all")
@GET
@RBAC(type = { CRUDEnum.READ }, capability = { "PowerUser" })
@ParseContext
@Produces( {
        "application/json",
        "application/xml"})
public net.myapp.services getAllDevices(
        @QueryParam("start") int param0, @QueryParam("limit") int param1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way for this. There is no REST annotation to add the parameter description.

The solution for this is to use the typical java-doc annotation.

e.g.

```
/** 
 * @param param0 Paging parameter
 * @param param1 Paging parameter
 * */
@Path("list-all")
@GET
@RBAC(type = { CRUDEnum.READ }, capability = { "PowerUser" })
@ParseContext
@Produces( {
        "application/json",
        "application/xml"})
public net.myapp.services getAllDevices(
        @QueryParam("start") int param0, @QueryParam("limit") int param1);
```